# flexbox adding newline to clipboard

Tags: css, clipboard, flexbox

I'm working with a layout that uses flexbox. Works good so far but I have a problem with copying text to clipboard.

Apparently, using flexbox seems to add a newline character after each child node

It can be seen in the demo below, copying text "LabelMessage" works normally (paste it and it remains one-line). But if you add `display:flex` to container a newline is added after "Label" upon copying to clipboard

What is causing this? Is there any way around it?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zv4mamtm/

```js
$('.toggleFlex').on('click', function() {
  $('.container').toggleClass('flex')
})
```

```css
.container.flex {
  display: flex;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="toggleFlex">toggle</span>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <span class="label">Label</span>
  <span class="label">Message</span>
</div>
<hr>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: This question already has an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/43846713/1926369

Comment: @vals oh, and for one moment I thought I was clever than Michael_B, I was dreaming :p

Comment: @vals "already" – it was asked 2 years later :P

But thanks, it does answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in the previous answer and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846713/removing-line-breaks-in-text-copied-from-a-flex-container) :

> In a flex container the child elements ("flex items") are automatically "blockified" ( [more details](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items) )

depending on your use case, using [display: contents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#display-box) can be helpful if you only want to copy / paste text,

see : [how display contents works](https://bitsofco.de/how-display-contents-works/)

> The easiest way to understand what happens when display: contents is used is to imagine the element’s opening and closing tags being omitted from the markup.

and from [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#box-generation) :

> For the purposes of box generation and layout, the element must be treated as if it had been replaced in the element tree by its contents

( you might want to check the compatibility of this as it won't work in IE and Edge )

[image]

```js
$('.toggleFlex').on('click', function() {
  $('.container').toggleClass('flex')
})
```

```css
.container.flex {
  display: flex;
  color: red;
}

.container.flex span {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="toggleFlex">toggle</span>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <span class="label">Label</span>
  <span class="label">Message</span>
</div>
<hr>
<textarea></textarea>
```

this will override the `display:block` of the `span` caused by th `flex` container :

[image]

Comment: pay attention to this, it doesn't remove the display block, it does remove the container and keep only content ... `For the purposes of box generation and layout, the element must be treated as if it had been replaced in the element tree by its contents` --> so it's like you have this `<div class="container">
  Label
  Message
</div>`. No more span so no more issue and you are no more able to style each word alone

Comment: This makes the text uncopyable when flex is enabled on Firefox 60.

Comment: @TemaniAfif , it's *treated* like that, the `DOM` is not affected and you won't loose any tag , so you can style every word, check this : http://jsfiddle.net/zv4mamtm/8/ , unless i misunderstood your comment

Comment: check this : http://jsfiddle.net/zv4mamtm/9/ you can no more style them (no margin, centring, etc) this is what I meant. I know the DOM is *never* affect by CSS, but it's treated *like* there is no wrapper, so since there is no more wrapper you lose all the abilties of common styling

Comment: @TemaniAfif i see what you mean, it's not a suitable solution if you want to style the `span` ( flex-items ) but that's why i added *depending on your use case* , addressing the line break issue, funny though how you can only change the color ( and font size and weight .. )

Comment: Yes, but it's not funny I guess it's a *bug* or something special with these styles, I need to deep into the Spec to see why we can style color, font-size, etc as it shouldn't be