# How to have a span inside a word without breaking it on wrap?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm making a lyrics sheet with chords. If I put the chord (as a span) inside a word for exact positioning, it means that word will break in half if the line wraps. How could I keep the word together?

[image]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96h8kfw9/

Code: 
CSS

```
.chord {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 34px;
    width: 0px;
    color: blue;
    white-space: pre;
}
.line {
    min-height: 12px;
    width: 285px;
}

.line-text {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="line">
<span class="line-text">
  Hello this is a line that wraps with a brok<span class="chord">C#</span>en word.
</span>
</div>
```

**edit:**
I do want wrap, but on the whole word, not breaking a word in half.

Comment: maybe you can do this differently .. check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092108/align-guitar-chords-on-web/50092148#50092148

Comment: Why do you use `inline-block` in `.chord`? I think you, just, need to remove the `display: inline-block` from `.chord`.

Comment: @SaidbakR `inline-block` lets me increase the height of the chord span, so the chord will appear above the text instead of covering it.

Comment: @TemaniAfif that example uses absolute positioning. I _could_ do that, but by giving my chord span a height, the lines with chords have space for the chords, and lines without chords (like other stanzas) aren't spaced

Comment: ok here is another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359121/make-selector-contribute-to-element-width/50359172#50359172 they are just ideas :) as actually i don't see a solution for your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
.chord {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  white-space: pre;
}

.chord span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  width: 0px;
  color: blue;
  white-space: pre;
}

.line {
  min-height: 12px;
  width: 285px;
}

.line-text {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

EDIT: Updated to remove white-space: pre-wrap on .line-text class to stop space appearing at start of line.

https://jsfiddle.net/richjava/n1ro4o1a/

Comment: Updated to remove white-space: pre-wrap on .line-text class to stop space appearing at start of line.

Comment: This works, but requires adding a container span around any word with a chord inside—that gets tricky when there are multiple chords in a word.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.chord {
    height: 34px;
    width: 0px;
    color: blue;
}
.line {
    min-height: 12px;
    width: 285px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.line-text {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear—I do want wrap, but I want the whole word to wrap, not break in half (I want to break on spaces)

Answer (score 0):

you could keep the words together by adding a non-breaking space tag within various places you don't want to break in the HTML code:

1. Using `&nbsp;`

Example:

`This&nbsp;is&nbsp;not&nbsp;A&nbsp;convenient&nbsp;but&nbsp;efficient&nbsp;way&nbsp;to&nbsp;prevent&nbsp;line&nbsp;breaks`

Will display (On the same line without breaking):
This is not A convenient but efficient way to prevent line breaks

2. Using `<nobr>`
   This is a non-standard element but has worked in some browsers that I have used  (IE, Firefox, ) and am sure would work for most.

`<nobr> The tag should enclose the word or sentence you don't want to break</nobr>`

Will display the word you want together without breaking. 
Hope this helps

Comment: I'm happy with breaks on spaces, the problem is breaking halfway through a word (because of the span inside the word)