# How to display text relative to word in line with CSS+HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

We code as team a parserfor text-files in [onsong](https://onsongapp.com/docs/features/formats/onsong/) or [chordpro](https://onsongapp.com/docs/features/formats/chordpro/)-syntax and render them to html. You can find the source at [github](https://github.com/GebetshausFreiburg/songbook.printer).

It works fine, but now we want to render plain html as clean as possible. For that we want to use css. So far we found a solution you can watch at jsfiddle. For chords we use the [css-solution (see jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/0adkhxe7/122/)

```
<span class="chord"><span class="inner">E</span></span>

.chord { 
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: red;
 }

 .chord .inner {
   position: relative;
   top: -1em;
 }
```

Now we have the problem that the chord at the end of the song are not correctly shown because there os no line-text between the following chords. The chord should be shown as H E Asus2.

Is it possible to solve this with CSS or need we to apply a solution in java by checking the elements in the sond to "force" some  .

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Java or javascript? big difference. My guess JS

Comment: I'm being confused here, i'm used to see the chords below the lyrics, not on top of it. how ever, it seems readable to me.

Comment: why not using them inside the same chord?

Comment: @G-Cyr check the last one, there is 3 overlapping

Comment: oh yes, without lyrics, your absolute span are written on the same spot. https://jsfiddle.net/0adkhxe7/124/ some kind of silence are to be added there

Comment: I would propose you to break and wrap your lyrics into span to follow the tempo. on each span you can use a data-attribute (or an extra tag to insert the chord to play. . Make those span so much em width to stick to lyrics bits 's length , where ther is no lyrics, the span without text will occuppy the roon to show the chords

Comment: this is somehow similar to what you are doing : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359121/make-selector-contribute-to-element-width/50359172#50359172 you may probably get some ideas

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not what you need, but my idea is that you can use a `::before` pseudo element instead of `<span class="chord"><span class="inner">D</span></span>`.

```css
.lyrics{
line-height:3em;
font-family: "Century Gothic",CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;}
.lyrics span{
  position:relative;
  /*border:1px solid red;*/
}
.lyrics span::before{
  content:attr(data-chord);
  position:absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  bottom: .2em;
  left:0;
  text-align:center;
  color:red;
  width:100%;
  /*border:1px solid green;*/
}
```

```html
<p class="lyrics">1. I can only <span data-chord="D">imagine</span> what it will be like when <span data-chord="G">I walk</span> by Your side.</p>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: similar idea to my comment, you can also use my pen https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/OozPaX

Comment: @G-Cyr yes but it's on the top not the bottom :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif as i commented, that's the way i'm used to read it ;) (never had any teacher ... just picking up by the fire camps)